# Regex replace between two words

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace set of string between two characters say `&` and `[]` with some other value. For example, my string is like `&yyyyyyy[]=&gggggg[]=&bbbbb[]=`. Now I want to replace the string between `&` and `[]` with "name" so that it looks like `&name[]=&name[]=&name[]=`. Now how to do it?

Comment: With `preg_replace` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = '&yyyyyyy[]=&gggggg[]=&bbbbb[]=';
$result = preg_replace('/&([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\[\]/', '&name[]', $string);

// Outputs: &name[]=&name[]=&name[]=
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/&([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\[\]/', '&name[]', "&yyyyyyy[]=&gggggg[]=&bbbbb[]=");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it..

using `preg_replace`or `preg_replace_callback`

```
\&(.*?)\[]
```

this should match the strings between character & and character []

```
preg_match_all('#\&(.*?)\[]#','&yyyyyyy[]=&gggggg[]=&bbbbb[]=',$matches);
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "&yyyyyyy[]" [1]=> string(9) "&gggggg[]" [2]=> string(8) "&bbbbb[]" } 
           [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "yyyyyyy" [1]=> string(6) "gggggg" [2]=> string(5) "bbbbb" } }
```

this regex is the closest i can get. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want and should match anything between & and [] that is not &, [], or =

```
$subject = '&yyyyyyy[]=&gggggg[]=&bbbbb[]=';    
$pattern = '/&([^\[\]\&=]+)\[\]/';
$replacement = '&name[]';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject, -1);
```