# replace everything between two words and also two words in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text like this

```
0367118 06 - 10 000071
Bank sl. no beginning with an 'IA' indicates ICB account
Paramount Textile Limited Page No: 113 of 258
Lottery Conducted by--Dept. of Electrical and Electronic Engineering, BUET. Date:03/10/2013
General
Applicants
0367121 06 - 10 000074
```

want make it like this in Notepad++ using replace and regular expression

```
0367118 06 - 10 000071
0367121 06 - 10 000074
```

want to replace all between two word Bank and Applicants and also those word too with none.

Comment: show us your attempt!

Comment: This question is kind of to be asked ratjer on SuperUser not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

`Bank.*Applicants` does work except unchecking "matchs new line", so what you need to do is to check this box. I test it on Notepad ++ 6.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Just open replace dialog window.

Select *Regular expression* and tick *. matches newlines*.

Into find what type: Bank.*Applicants

Click replace all.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to do some programatically

This may be help you :

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611403/regex-replace-between-two-words)

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = text.replace(/(.*)Bank.+Applicants(.+)/, function(m,p1,p2) { return p1+p2;});
```

Comment: I believe he's looking for a Notepad++ replace, not coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a more generic solution than specifically replacing on the words "Bank" and "Applicants". Otherwise, you would do this manually.

So here's how to search for that *type* of code and replace what's in between:

```
Find:    (\d+ \d+ - \d+ \d+\r\n).*?(\d+ \d+ - \d+ \d+\r\n)
Replace: \1\2
```

Be sure you are using the "regular expression" mode, with ". matches newline" checked.

Comment: he want's to replace everything between Bank and Applicants! see the question..;)